# How to get an attribute from contextListener?

Tags: jsp, servlets, web

So I have this class (from which I deleted some methods to minimize your work):

```
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList();
    ServletContext context ;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        try {        
            this.getProductsFromDB(); // this method puts the products in the arraylist
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        context = sce.getServletContext();
        context.setAttribute("products", products);
    }
```

and I want to get the `ArrayList` in a JSP page like this :

```
<%! ArrayList<Product> products = (ArrayList<Product>)getServletContext().getAttribute("products"); %>
```

but actually it does not work.

Comment: Is your listener registered in the `web.xml`?

Comment: yes , it is . i got the attribute in a servlet and it worked . in the jsp page it does not

Answer (score 1):

Use *JSTL* like this

```
${applicationScope['products']}
```

or just the attribute name

```
${products}
```

Note : Scriptlets are **NOT** recommended.

You have to iterate the list using `c:forEach` tag in JSTL

```
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
  <li><c:out value="${product.field}"/></li>
 </c:forEach>
```

Where `field` denotes a property in `Product` Java bean

Comment: but how can i assign this to an ArrayList ?

Comment: You have assigned the list to the application scope attribute `products`. You can retrieve the list in the jsp using **JSTL**

Comment: i am new to jst , i just started and it does not work for me . may you add the code for retriving the list ?

Comment: Can you add the code for `getProductsFromDB` method? I'would like to make sure that you are actually setting data in it

Comment: i am , because i can read data from it in a servlet with request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("products"); but i don't know in jsp i did not understand where to put that ${products} because i need  foreach on that array

Comment: it worked for me finally with (ArrayList<Product>)application.getAttribute("products") but i don't know how to assign this to the arrayList because in <%! %> application is not any more visible.

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer to let the passers-by know that this question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it to fully qualified names.

```
<%
   java.util.ArrayList<Product> products = (java.util.ArrayList<you.package.for.Product>) getServletContext().getAttribute("products");
   pageContext.setAttribute("products", products);
%>
```

Nextly, you should be able to call it by its attribute name:

```
${products}
```

Comment: You didnt provide fully what you would like to achieve - I fixed scriptlet that you have written :) Code got rewritten so you should be able to use data from your scriptlet in JSP